# Função não reconhecida

Tags: php, symfony-2

Olá eu tenho o seguinte código:

> **Código antigo:**

```
public function historicoAction() {
     $entity = new Intervencao();
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $entities = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->findAll();
     $maquinas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();

     $prevista = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();

     $entity->setDescricao($prevista->getDescricao());

     return array(
          'entity' => $entity,
          'entities' => $entities,            
          'maquinas' => $maquinas,
     );
}
```

Esta-me a dar o seguinte erro:

> Error: Call to a member function getDescricao() on a non-object in /var/www/roqsys/src/RoqSys/Control/ManutencaoBundle/Controller/IntervencaoController.php line 76

---

### Edit**

> **Código novo:**

Tentei o seguinte:

```
public function historicoAction() {
    $entity = new Intervencao();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->findAll();
    $maquinas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();

    $prevista = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();
    var_dump($prevista);
    foreach($prevista as $obj) {
        echo $prevista->getDescricao();
    }
    $entity->setDescricao($prevista->getDescricao());

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'entities' => $entities,  
        'prevista' => $prevista,
        'maquinas' => $maquinas,
    );
}
```

E mesmo assim dá-me o mesmo erro.

Comment: Confira se a linha `$prevista = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();` Retorna um objeto válido.

Comment: Verifique se sua entidade (Entity) tem o método get definido

Comment: @Adir Kunhn a entity intervencao ou prevista????

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre na $prevista

Comment: Ahh, agora que eu vi o findAll() ele vai retornar um Array de Objetos, então você tem que fazer um foreach para dar um get de cada elemento

Comment: @Pedro Henrique a linha está a retorna um objecto, está a reportar as previstas.

Comment: @Adir Kuhn como??????

Answer (score 2):

A variável prevista está sendo retornada possivelmente como um array de objeto, tente verificar com o comando var_dump

```
var_dump($prevista);
```

Para pegar os valores de ´$prevista´ vc tem que fazer um loop

```
foreach($prevista as $obj) {
    echo $obj->getDescricao();
}
```

---

Se quiser pegar apenas um elemento dessa entidade vc precisa ter o id dela
e usar o

```
$prevista  = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->find($idPrevista);
```

Ai sim sera retornado apenas uma entidade e você pode usar direto o get

```
$prevista->getDescricao();
```

Comment: dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: tinha colocado $prevista no lugar de $obj

Comment: ainda não deu? posta o conteúdo do var_dump na sua pergunta ou no pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro acontece porque quando você usa o método `findAll` do `EntityRepository` (do Doctrine), ele retorna uma coleção de objetos – ou, mais especificamente, um `ArrayCollection`. No seu caso, é retornado um `ArrayCollection` de objetos do tipo `Prevista`.

Assim sendo, você precisa iterar por essa coleção para então chamar o método `getDescricao` da entidade `Prevista`:

```
$entity = new Intervencao();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entities  = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->findAll();
$maquinas  = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();
$previstas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();

foreach ($previstas as $prevista) {
     $entity->setDescricao($prevista->getDescricao());
}
```